# Create Horizontal + Vertical Scrolling Website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create a website with a scrolling effect like the following:
[Scrolling Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSteI.png)

The height of the middle section is dynamic and may change while the first and last sections have full-screen heights. Can you suggest any library or way to create such a scrolling effect?

Comment: so you are saying first and last section will take max window height, but second section will take dynamic height ? 

so in one page first section will scroll horizontally, second will scroll vertically and third will scroll horizontally again ?

You don't need any library for that, as it can be achieved via HTML/CSS

Comment: @prograk OP wants the vertical scroll to scroll horizontal, then vertical, then horizontal. You can't achieve that purely with HTML/CSS. You need JS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have shown section 2 as narrower than the other sections - do you want bits of the other sections to show when you are showing section 2 or do you want it, say, to be centered on the viewport (horizontally)? Also do you want the scrolling between sections to be smooth (gradual, section one going out to the left while section 2 comes in)?

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry for missing out details, section 2 being narrower is just an error, all the sections will take 100 viewport widths. And, yes, if possible, smooth scrolling will be a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer (what OP wants):**
Ok so this question is poorly stated but after understanding what we want to achieve, possibly the only way to do that with a dynamic content is to use `grid` block rows. See the below sample (I will also keep my initial answer since I believe is a far "cleaner" way):

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const allPanels = gsap.utils.toArray(".panel");
const triggerPanels = gsap.utils.toArray(".panel:not(.last)");

triggerPanels.forEach(function (panel, i) {
  gsap.fromTo( allPanels,
    { xPercent: -(100 * i) },
    {
      xPercent: -(100 * (i + 1)),
      immediateRender: false,
      ease: "none",
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: panel,
        id: "panel-" + i,
        start: () => "bottom bottom",
        end: () => "+=" + document.querySelector(".panel").offsetWidth,
        pin: ".container",
        pinnedContainer: ".container",
        scrub: 0.2, // Change this for a "smoother transition" effect
      }
    }
  );
});

ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("refresh", clear);
function clear() {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < ScrollTrigger.getById("panel-0").start){
    gsap.set(allPanels, { clearProps: "xPercent" });
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-x: hidden;font-size: 20px;font-family: sans-serif;color: white;}
.container {display: grid;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;grid-template-rows: 1fr 1px 1px 1px;}

/* Width -4rem due to padding */
.panel {position: relative;width: calc(100vw - 4rem);padding: 2rem;}
.p1 {height: calc(100vh - 4rem);background: firebrick;grid-column: 1 / 2;grid-row: 1 / 2;}
.p2 {background: teal;grid-column: 2 / 3;grid-row: 1 / 3;}
.p3 {background: orange;grid-column: 3 / 4;grid-row: 2 / 4;margin-top: -100vh;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel p1">
      <h2>100 VH</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel p2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sollicitudin ante vitae tempor pulvinar. Nunc placerat volutpat augue. Maecenas cursus velit vitae velit aliquet faucibus. Mauris eget libero est. Nullam scelerisque nisl at tristique
        lobortis. Nullam nunc enim, posuere a auctor et, scelerisque nec diam. Maecenas sed nunc ante. Vestibulum iaculis molestie placerat. Maecenas iaculis, lectus vitae congue iaculis, nunc arcu elementum lorem, vitae mattis diam neque eget justo.
        Nulla facilisi. Phasellus at dignissim elit. Nam pretium purus tortor, sit amet dapibus erat mattis sit amet. Curabitur scelerisque commodo dolor iaculis sollicitudin. Aliquam felis lacus, pellentesque nec rhoncus mollis, gravida quis odio. Duis
        sed dapibus augue, eleifend mattis ligula. Aliquam interdum maximus nisl tempus viverra.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sollicitudin ante vitae tempor pulvinar. Nunc placerat volutpat augue. Maecenas cursus velit vitae velit aliquet faucibus. Mauris eget libero est. Nullam scelerisque nisl at tristique
        lobortis. Nullam nunc enim, posuere a auctor et, scelerisque nec diam. Maecenas sed nunc ante. Vestibulum iaculis molestie placerat. Maecenas iaculis, lectus vitae congue iaculis, nunc arcu elementum lorem, vitae mattis diam neque eget justo.
        Nulla facilisi. Phasellus at dignissim elit. Nam pretium purus tortor, sit amet dapibus erat mattis sit amet. Curabitur scelerisque commodo dolor iaculis sollicitudin. Aliquam felis lacus, pellentesque nec rhoncus mollis, gravida quis odio. Duis
        sed dapibus augue, eleifend mattis ligula. Aliquam interdum maximus nisl tempus viverra.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel p3 last">
      <h2>100 VH AGAIN</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Initial Answer:**
Since OP asks about third-party libraries, you can use [GSAP Scroll Trigger](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger) for free.
There you go, please check the comments in the snippet to understand how this works.

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const horizontally = gsap.utils.toArray(".horizontally");

horizontally.forEach(element => {
  gsap.to(element, {
    xPercent: -50, // To make this responsive if you add 200vw to horizontal divs
                   // then you need to make this scroll 50% right, because your screen
                   // already shows the 100vw.
    ease: "none",
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: element,
      pin: true,
      scrub: 1,
      end: () => "+=" + document.querySelector(".horizontally").offsetWidth
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {padding: 0;margin: 0;overflow-x: hidden;}

.horizontally {
  width: 200vw; /* Set this according to your JS settings */
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #000, #222);
}

.vertically {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #222, #444);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://assets.codepen.io/16327/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/gsap-latest-beta.min.js"></script>

<div class="horizontally">
  <h2>Scroll Horizontally</h2>
  <p>Really long text that will go on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on</p>
</div>
<div class="vertically">
  <h2>Scroll Vertically</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sollicitudin ante vitae tempor pulvinar. Nunc placerat volutpat augue. Maecenas cursus velit vitae velit aliquet faucibus. Mauris eget libero est. Nullam scelerisque nisl at tristique lobortis. Nullam nunc enim, posuere a auctor et, scelerisque nec diam. Maecenas sed nunc ante. Vestibulum iaculis molestie placerat. Maecenas iaculis, lectus vitae congue iaculis, nunc arcu elementum lorem, vitae mattis diam neque eget justo. Nulla facilisi.</p>
</div>
<div class="horizontally">
  <h2>Scroll Horizontally</h2>
  <p>Really long text that will go on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Your solution is good, but that it is different from what I am trying to create. I am trying to create something like this but just with three sections. [sample codepen](https://codepen.io/akapowl/pen/LYOERPv). But the issue with this solution is that, if we cannot specify the height of one of the sections, then the whole animation falls apart. [Problem](https://codepen.io/vasudevsall/pen/oNoVbPY)

Comment: @vdev i just tested it, you can remove the height from vertical sections and is working fine: [Pen](https://codepen.io/gestok/pen/NWwJerw). I updated my answer's code as well.

Comment: @vdev ok I now see what you mean. Your sketch is really not showing what you are trying to achieve.. entirely different structure. You do not need horizontal divs, just a horizontal transition from one section to another.

Comment: @vdev check my updated answer. Open in full size the 1st snippet and resize the window.

Comment: Thank You for your solution. And sorry for not making the question clear. Thank You so much.